# Top-like tool for IP traffic

Tags: linux, networking, debian, performance-monitoring

I need to keep watch on how much bandwidth some connections are taking in a server, and I know I have seen a top-like tool for that before. However, I can't remember the name of the tool, and I'm not having much luck searching for it.

So, is there a top-like tool for that? I'm running Debian.

Comment: what OS are you looking at?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[**`iftop`**](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) or [**`pktstat -nT`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pktstat) (for short term monitoring) is what you need to do this (under *nix).  For long-term monitoring, [**`ntop`**](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) is useful.

Finding [`pktstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pktstat) is a little tricky for those who aren't running a Debian / Ubuntu box, but this is a decent [`pktstat` source-code archive](http://pktstat.sourcearchive.com/)

Use [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) if you want the same kind of stats under windows

Comment: Tested ntop and it is pretty neat. However, the man page sucks to say where it saves the data to read after a run.

Answer (score 11):

You might also want to have a look at [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/).

Answer (score 4):

There's also [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) which shows traffic per process, most of the popular distros have a package for it.

Answer (score 4):

I am partial for [pktstat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pktstat). It can easily also show real-time data on the traffic as URLs for HTTP GETs, queries for DNS, etc.

Comment: Ok, I'm really enjoying pktstat. I like iftop's display better, but seeing the URLs is particularly useful for me at the moment! I'll stick with my original accepted answer on the grounds that it provided a Windows alternative as well, and that iftop does the job.

Answer (score 1):

jnettop is my personal favorite. Seems to exist for most distros. Ref: http://jnettop.kubs.info/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

There is also ntop, although it isn't terminal based anymore.